# Do I need to catch each individual exception type if I'm going to perform the same action?

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, .net-3.5

Simply put, I don't expect this application to receive too many errors since it's a fairly controlled environment and the users are other developers.

Having said that, errors *do* happen sooner or later and I simply just want to keep a log of them and alert the user. I've got this method that tries to validate the information as best as it can, then it tries to copy a file from A to B.

```
        try
        {
            File.Copy(source, destination, true);
            return String.Empty;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logOp.AddLog(ex);
            return string.Format("ERROR: {0}{1}{2}", ex.Message, Environment.NewLine, ex.StackTrace);
        }
```

The method returns an empty string if it was successful, and if not it logs the exception and returns it to the calling method for presentation.

Do I need to catch each individual Exception type that File.Copy can throw if I want the most detailed Message / Stack trace, or will just catching Exception work? I tried hardcoding it to throw new instances of the various Exceptions and it seems OK but I wasn't sure if there was some programming principle I was missing/violating

Comment: You use `String.Empty` to signal success?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all you're doing in exception handler is logging, then I'd say no, just take the Exception and log the message.

Catching individual exceptions would be useful if you attempted to recover from the error.

Comment: Yea, initially I had like 10 different Catch blocks for each individual one, then realized how god awful it looked since each one was doing the exact same thing. Just wasn't sure if this single "top level" catch would actual work out in practice.

Answer (score 1):

I would keep it as is and just catch the base class Exception.

Logging the ex.ToString() like you implicitly do in logOp.AddLog(ex) should write the actual type of the exception (which could be one of these that File.Copy method can throw [in the Exceptions section here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a.aspx) )

Based on that link, the name of the actual exception should be informative enough since you are not attempting to recover from the exceptions, just logging them.